# Pertinence of JWT with HTTPS

Tags: https, token, jwt

If I use https for my website, is JWT still relevant ?

I mean, why a "simple" key : data (for instance) in the http header would not be enough ? (Ok, it is a little bit harsh, but...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because anyone could create fake tokens

Https encrypts the channel, but it does not authenticate the client side except if you are using client certificates

JWT is mainly used for authentication. It includes a signature to ensure that is has been issued by the server and it has not been altered. If you omit the signature, an attacker could easily call your API with a fake user Id, roles or anydata that the server expects in the http header